# Landscape table over multiple pages layout issues

Tags: tables, formatting, landscape, layout

I have some issues with a landscape table i split over multiple pages that i want to use in the appendix of my thesis.

I incorporated it like this (in order not to mess up my main file):

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anhang}\section*{Anhang} \label{anhang}
\section*{A\, Anpassung der eingesetzten Skalen}
\input{appendixtable}
```

The *first issue* is, that it doesn´t start on the same page as the two headings, probably because it's too wide. Is it possible, to let it start on this page?

*Second problem:* Since the rows of the table aren't equally high/tall, one line is on one single page, is it possible to manage this in some way (see the two screenshots below)

*Third issue:* After the table is finished, LaTex reproduces the top line with the headings of the table one more time on a seperate page, is there any way to remove this?

And I'd have one extra question, does anyone know a way, to generate those pages with landscape tables in landscape mode automatically, so that you don't have to rotate the PDF for these pages?

Find my MWE here:

```
\documentclass[parsikip=full,oneside, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.8cm, right=2.8cm,top=2.1cm, bottom=19mm,includehead=false,footskip=10mm, bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{microtype}      
\usepackage{color}          

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linktoc = all, draft = false, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}




\clubpenalty=10000                                          % Verhindert einzelne Absatzzeile am Ende oder am Anfang
\widowpenalty=10000                                         % einer Seite.
\displaywidowpenalty=10000                                  %
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}

\newcommand{\anf}[1]{\glqq{}#1{}\grqq{}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
%   \renewcommand{\BCBL}{,}%
%   \renewcommand{\BCBT}{,}%
}




\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\setcounter{page}{1}\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{Einleitung}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

    \newpage

        
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anhang}\section*{Anhang} \label{anhang}
\section*{A\, Anpassung der eingesetzten Skalen}
        
\input{anhangtabelle}
\end{document}
```

This is a shorter version of the table:

```
\begin{landscape}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{longtable}[c]{llll}
        \caption{übersicht}
        \label{anpassung-skalen}\\
        \hline
        Konstrukt &
        Ursprüngliche Skala &
        Eigene Skala &
        Quelle \\ \hline
        \endhead
        %
        \hline
        \endfoot
        %
        \endlastfoot
        %
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}PIM-\\ Prosumption\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(1) browse content, (2) contribute originalddddddgggg on\\ content to, (3) comment or rate content on,\\ (4) share content with others on social \\ networking sites and microblogging services\\ (e.g. Twitter), respectively\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(1) Browsing political internet memesdddddd99998\\ \\ (1) Browsing political internet memes on social \\ media, (2) Contributing original political internet \\ memes to social media, (3) Commenting or rating \\ political internet memes on social media, \\ (4) Sharing political internet memes with others \\ on social media\end{tabular} &
        \parencite{yamamotopro} \\
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Wahrgenommene\\ Ungerechtigkeit\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(1) It’s an injustice that the victims of harassment suffer \\ from slutshaming, (2) It’s wrongful conduct that some \\ employers intentionally avoid punishing sexual harassers, \\ (3) I feel outraged when sexual harassment victims are \\ thwarted from protecting their rights\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(1) It’s an injustice that many politicians don’t care\\ about the climate crisis, (2) It’s wrongful conduct \\ that politics don’t stick to the Paris Agreement, (3) I \\ feel outraged when climate activists aren’t heard\end{tabular} &
        \parencite{zhou} \\

    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: first issue is by design, `landscape` starts and ends with `\clearpage` so it starts a new page even if the content is empty, so unrelated to the table width, 2nd issue you have to fix by hand splitting the large cell into two longtable rows (I would use top alignment, vertical centred text looks odd). (why are you using nested tabular and doing the line breaking in the cells by hand?) third issue, provide an example and someone can debug, but also make sure you haev an up to date longtable version (4.15 or 4.16) fourth issue should be automatic if you use pdflscape to define the landscape env

Comment: Is a table really the best way to display this kind of information? Probably a nested list would be better?

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not directly answer your question, here is an alternative approach on how to present this information without the need to a) rotate the page, b) manually adjust line and page breaks and c) manually number the individual statements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
        
\footnotesize
\begin{itemize}
  \item PIM-Prosumption \parencite{yamamotopro}
  \begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
    \begin{paracol}{2}
      Ursprüngliche Skala:
    \switchcolumn[1]
      Eigene Skala:
    \switchcolumn[0]*
    %
      \item browse content, 
    \switchcolumn[1]  
      \item  Browsing political internet memes on social  media,
    \switchcolumn[0]*
    %
      \item contribute originalddddddgggg on content to, 
    \switchcolumn[1]  
      \item Contributing original political internet memes to social media, 
    \switchcolumn[0]*  
    %
      \item comment or rate content on,
    \switchcolumn[1]
      \item Commenting or rating  political internet memes on social media,
    \switchcolumn[0]*  
    %
      \item share content with others on social  networking sites and microblogging services (e.g. Twitter), respectively
    \switchcolumn[1]
      \item Sharing political internet memes with others on social media
    \end{paracol}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}  

\begin{itemize}
  \item PIM-Prosumption \parencite{yamamotopro}
  \begin{paracol}{2}
    Ursprüngliche Skala:
    \switchcolumn[1]
    Eigene Skala:
    \switchcolumn[0]*
    \begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
      \item browse content,
      \item contribute originalddddddgggg on content to, 
      \item comment or rate content on,
      \item share content with others on social networking sites and microblogging services (e.g. Twitter), respectively
    \end{enumerate}
    \switchcolumn[1]
    \begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
      \item Browsing political internet memes on social  media, 
      \item Contributing original political internet memes to social media, 
      \item Commenting or rating political internet memes on social media, 
      \item Sharing political internet memes with others on social media
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{paracol}
\end{itemize}       

\end{document}
```